# getting ORA-01031: insufficient privileges while executing SYS.DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE.DECLARE _REWRITE_EQUIVALENCE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I got the error `ORA-01031`: insufficient privileges while executing  `SYS.DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE.DECLARE _REWRITE_EQUIVALENCE` procedure. I executed the statement from normal user hr.

Even granting following execute permission to user `HR` as `SYSDBA` did not resolve issue.
`GRANT EXECUTE ON  DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE` TO hr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_advrwr.htm#i999466

Try to grant materialsed view privileges for equivalence creation.

```
GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO hr;
```

Comment: Thank you Rogue. I had gone  through the above docs but did not notice above materialized view privileges grant statement.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!